# Disable Look Up & Share on text selection in uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

How to disable "Look Up" and "Share" only on text selection in uitextfield. Below is the swift code what i have tried

```
override public func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(copy(_:)) || action == #selector(paste(_:)) || action == #selector(delete(_:)) || action == #selector(cut(_:))
        {
            return true
        } else if action == Selector(("_lookup:")) || action == Selector(("_share:")) || action == Selector(("_define:")) {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
```

I want to show only cut, copy, paste & delete with and without text selection.

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me to disable Share but not Look up. If you could find sth about disabling Look Up please update me. Plus, don't forget to change the class of your textField to the CustomUITextField class in Storyboard Identity Inspector

```swift
class CustomUITextField: UITextField {

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        
        if action.description.contains("_share")
        {
            return false
        }

        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class CustomActionTextField: UITextField {
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action.description.contains("_share") // block "Share"
            || action.description.contains("_translate") // block "Translate"
            || action.description.contains("_define") // block "Look Up" {
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }
}
```

you can check more action with `print(action.description)`